# Parsing ByteString from Socket fails

Tags: sockets, haskell

We are writing a message broker in Haskell [(HMB)](https://github.com/hmb-ba/broker). Therefore messages have to be parsed ([Data.Binary](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.7.4.0/docs/Data-Binary.html)) after they are received from socket ([Network.Socket](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-2.6.1.0/docs/Network-Socket.html#v:socket)). We've been testing on loopback (localhost) so far - for producing and parsing messages. This worked quiet well. If we benchmark by producing messages from another machine we are facing problems: Suddenly the parser does not have enough bytes to parse.

The first 4 bytes of each message defines the length of the message and thus describes the message to be parsed. As hinted above, we do parsing with Data.Binary - so this is lazy. For testing purposes we switched parsing of the first 4 bytes to strict by using the cereal library. This the same problem. We now even tried to completely parse the requests with cereal only and the problem also remains.

In the code you'll see that we do threading. However, we also tried without a channel (single threaded setup) but this didn't solve the problem either.

Here is a part of the code (Thread1) where the received bytes are written to a channel to be further consumed/parsed. (As mentioned, nothing changes if we omit channeling and directly parse *input*):

```
runConnection :: (Socket, SockAddr) -> RequestChan -> Bool -> IO()
runConnection conn chan False = return ()
runConnection conn chan True = do
    r <- recvFromSock conn
    case (r) of
        Left e -> do
            handleSocketError conn e
            runConnection conn chan False
        Right input -> do
            threadDelay 5000 -- THIS FIXES THE PROBLEM!?
            writeToReqChan conn chan input
            runConnection conn chan True
```

Here is the part (Thread2) where *input* is beeing parsed:

```
runApiHandler :: RequestChan -> ResponseChan -> IO()
runApiHandler rqChan rsChan = do
  (conn, req) <- readChan rqChan
  case readRequest req of -- readRequest IS THE PARSER
    Left (bs, bo, e) -> handleHandlerError conn $ ParseRequestError e
    Right (bs, bo, rm) -> do
      res <- handleRequest rm
      case res  of
        Left e -> handleHandlerError conn e
        Right bs -> writeToResChan conn rsChan bs
  runApiHandler rqChan rsChan
```

Now I figured out, that if the process of parsing is delayed a bit (see threadDelay in the first code block), everything works fine. Which basically means, the parser doesn't wait for bytes received from the socket.

Why is that? Why does the parser not wait for the socket the have enough bytes? Is there a general mistake in our setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would bet that the problem has nothing to do with the parser but is instead due to the blocking semantics of UNIX sockets.

While a loopback
interface will likely pass the packet directly from the sender to the receiver,
an Ethernet interface may need to break up the packet to fit in the Maximum
Transmission Unit (MTU) of the link. This is known as packet fragmentation.

The `len`
argument to the [`recv`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) system call is merely
the upper bound on the received length (e.g. the size of the target buffer); the
call may produce less data than you ask for. To quote the manpage,

> If no messages are available at the socket, the receive calls wait for a
>   message to arrive, unless the socket is nonblocking (see fcntl(2)), in which
>   case the value -1 is returned and the external variable errno is set to
>   EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK.  The receive calls normally return any data
>   available, up to the requested amount, rather than waiting for receipt of
>   the full amount requested.

For this reason, you may need multiple `recv` calls to retrieve the entire packet. Your example works if you delay the `recv` as the operating system can reassemble the original packet since all fragments have arrived by the time it is requested.

As [meiersi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30377965/1102851) pointed out, there are a variety of streaming I/O libraries that have developed in the Haskell world for solving this problem, among others. These include [`pipes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.5/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html), [`conduit`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit), [`io-streams`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/io-streams), and others. Depending upon your goals, this may be a natural way to handle this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try [the socket support in `conduit-extra`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-extra-1.1.8/docs/Data-Conduit-Network.html) combined with [`binary-conduit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-conduit) to properly handle the parsing of the chunked streaming, which happens due to the reasons pointed out by [bgamari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1102851/bgamari).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, consider yourself lucky to observe this. On many platforms perhaps only one out of a thousand packets exhibit this behaviour, causing a lot of such (sorry) bad networking code to fail seldom and randomly.

The problem is that you start processing before the data is ready. Instead of the threadDelay (which introduces a permanent delay and might not be long enough in all cases), the solution is to make sure you have at least one item/message/packet to process before you start processing it. Your protocol where the first 32bit word contains the length is perfect for this. Read data until you have at least 4 bytes (the length). Then read data until you have the required number of bytes. If any calls to recvFromSock returns less than the required number, call it again to get some more. Remember to also handle the case of 0 bytes, this means the other party closed the connection.

I have implemented this for a similar protocol (SMPP, packets also starts with the length) and it works perfectly.